# Check for parent category

Tags: categories, children

Code below is designed for testing to see if current post is in a category that is an ancestor (child/grandchild/greatgrandchild etc) of cat number 526

```
$cats = wp_get_post_categories();
if (cat_is_ancestor_of($cats[0],526)) {
echo "yes this works" ;
}
```

Not sure why this isnt working but likely something stupidly simple....

TIA

Comment: Just to clarify, ancestor refers to any cat UP the chain from it. So if 526 is the category, and you want to get its ancestors, that would be all the categories that have 526 as a child/grandchild, etc. That might be why the syntax is confusing in the cat_is_ancestor_of() call.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax of `cat_is_ancestor_of` is

```
cat_is_ancestor_of( $parent_cat_id, $child_cat_id );
```

Where:

**$parent_cat_id**: should be the id to check if this is the parent category, in your case it should be **526**.

**$child_cat_id**: should be the id of the child category.